# Adding an image when clicking on a row (<li> tag)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

To solve this problem, i had the idea to create a css class to add the image and when i click on "li",  i add the class to it. But for some reason, it just doesnt work. The row appear properly in the ui-grid, but when i click on it, the image doesnt appear. I already tested the onclick() event with an alert() and the function is called.

Since i begin in these languages, i just feel like im assuming things (for exemple, does $(this) really refer to the "li" tag?). If anyone have an idea, it would be appreciated. Here is my code :

**CSS**

```
checked
{
    background: url('images/checked.png') no-repeat right scroll;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
function isChecked()
{
    alert("test");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="addedParts" onclick="isChecked()">
    <a href="javascript:addParts();">
        <div class="ui-grid-solo">
            <div class="ui-block-a">test</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: in your css it should be `.checked`

Comment: Realised that it works with `li.checked`, but indeed, `.checked` is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this` will refer to `window` in your example as context is not passed.

Try this:

```js
function isChecked(elem) {
  $(elem).addClass("checked");
}
```

```css
.checked {
  background: url('images/checked.png') no-repeat right scroll;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="addedParts" onclick="isChecked(this)">
  <a>
    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
      <div class="ui-block-a">test</div>
    </div>
  </a>

</li>
```

Comment: Aww it was indeed the reference that i misinterpreted. Thank you!